# Square root [ASM]

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I'm having a bit of a hardship understanding how I could possibly perform this operation.

```
    float squared( float num )
    {
       __asm
       {
           push   ebp
           mov    ebp, esp
           sub    esp, num
           xorps  xmm0, xmm0
           movss  dword ptr 4[ebp], xmm0
           movss  xmm0, dword ptr num[ebp]
           mulss  xmm0, dword ptr num[ebp]
           movss  dword ptr 8[ebp], xmm0
           fld    dword ptr 4[ebp]
           sqrtss xmm0, ebp
           movss  ebp, xmm0
           mov    esp,  ebp
           pop    ebp
           ret    0
       }
    }
```

I've worked in C / C++ for a while now, and it's always been a task of mine to really dig into how inline assembly works, but I'm having some problems when executing the code.

When I run this in my main function to print the root and insert a value, I'm given an error:

Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000. occurred

Any ideas?

Comment: Many things that make no sense. 1) `sub esp, num` 2) writing to `8[ebp]` overwrites your input `num` 3) using `fld` which is an x87 instruction in code doing SSE maths 4) `movss  dword ptr 4[ebp], xmm0` overwrites the return address 5) If you want a square root, why are you multiplying? 6) `movss  ebp, xmm0` 7) `num[ebp]`

Comment: Not sure what that code does... but it surely *not* compute the square root of a number.

Comment: If you want to dig into how assembly works I would suggest you to Google something like "x86 assembly square root" and start from there, don't try to reverse-engineer random copy-pasted assembly.

Comment: Some of the many mistakes you've made are an excellent demonstration why you shouldn't use inline assembly, and why you shouldn't use Microsoft's implementation in particular. In addition to the error zwol pointed out, `dword ptr num[ebp]` doesn't mean what you think it does. It's ends up being assembled as `dword ptr [ebp + ebp + 8]`. Both `sqrtss xmm0, ebp` and `movss  ebp, xmm0` are not valid instructions, there's no way to encode them, and should've been rejected by the compiler, but for some reason it accepted them anyway and generated different instructions. Just use sqrtf().

Comment: You should be calling your routine squareroot instead of squared, which has quite the opposite meaning.

Comment: You are creating and destroying the stack in your code, there's no need to do so in your inline asm code

Answer (score 3):

The most fundamental issue with this code is that you wrote your own function prologue and epilogue.  You have to do that when you are writing .ASM files entirely by hand, but you have to *not* do that when you write "inline" assembly embedded in C.  You have to let the compiler handle the stack.  This is the most likely reason why the program is crashing.  It also means that all of your attempts to access the `num` argument will instead access some unrelated stack slot, so even if your code didn't crash, it would take a garbage input,

As pointed out in comments on the question, you also have a bunch of nonsensical instructions in there, e.g. `sqrtss xmm0, ebp` (`sqrtss` cannot take integer register arguments).  This should have caused the compiler to reject the program, but if it instead produced nonsensical machine code, that could also cause a crash.

And (also as pointed out in comments on the question) I'm not sure what mathematical function this code would compute in the hypothetical scenario where each machine instruction does something like what you meant it to do, but it definitely *isn't* the square root.

Correct MSVC-style inline assembly to implement single-precision floating point square root, using the SSEn `sqrtss` instruction, would look something like this, I think.  (Not tested.  Since this is Win32 rather than Win64, an implementation using `fsqrt` instead might be more appropriate, but I don't know how to do that off the top of my head.)

```
float square_root(float radicand)
{
    __asm {
        sqrtss xmm0, radicand
    }
}
```

... Or you could just `#include <math.h>` and use `sqrtf` and save yourself the trouble.

Comment: `sqrtss` can't use a memory destination.  MSVC inline asm can only use memory inputs/outputs (unless you fall off the end of a non-void function with an integer return in EAX, or maybe an FP return in XMM0).  So maybe `sqrtss xmm0, radicand`, or also a `movss` store to `root`, if needed.  Of course that's terrible for performance, like MSVC inline asm in general for wrapping a single instruction.)

Comment: `fld radicand` ; `fsqrt` might work for an x87 return value.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, I haven't actually ever done anything serious with MSVC inline asm and I'm surprised to learn it can only use memory inputs/outputs.  I've adopted your `sqrtss xmm0, radicand` suggestion for the answer. Does it really let you fall off the end of the asm block with a return value in EAX or XMM0?  That wouldn't work with GCC, and MSVC's inliner is, if anything, even more aggressive.

Comment: Yes, MSVC inline asm really is designed that badly.  (Also it's apparently [unreliable in functions with register args](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/using-and-preserving-registers-in-inline-assembly?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019); that's only explainable by bad internal implementation which I guess would have needed a total rewrite for x86-64; instead they removed it.) And either by design or to avoid breaking code that took advantage as a hack, yes, MSVC really does support falling off the end with a value in EAX, even after inlining the function.  (IDK about XMM0)

Comment: See also [What is the difference between 'asm', '\_\_asm' and '\_\_asm\_\_'?](//stackoverflow.com/a/35959859) for some more links, and comparing how much it sucks to wrap a single instruction with MSVC `_asm` vs. GNU C inline `asm`.  See also Ross Ridge's comments on my answer there about MSVC `_asm` being unreliable, and Cody Gray's about the EAX return possibility.  [Does \_\_asm{}; return the value of eax?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36802683)

Comment: BTW; a `float` return value in the default 32-bit calling convention has to be in `st0`, not `xmm0`.  So you might need to use a `vectorcall` declspec or compile with `-Gv` for `sqrtss xmm0, var` to work.  But then you'd have a register arg which MSVC would have to spill.  With no code before the asm statement it might do that ok, I'm not sure.  Docs seem to say it's unsafe.  I don't actually use MSVC except on Godbolt to see how bad it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `fsqrt` from scratch will work.

```
fld qword [num]
fsqrt
```

Comment: `dword` *`ptr`* for MASM / MSVC-inline-asm syntax; also note that the OP's arg is a `float` not a `double`.  But yes, that should work in a calling convention that's expecting a float return value to be left in `st0`, assuming MSVC supports falling off the end of a non-void function with a return value in `st0` like it does for an integer in `eax`.